# Pfister's 16-Square Identity and the norm of sedenions

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, quaternions, octonions

Consider the sequence of numbers: complex numbers $\Bbb C$, quaternions $\Bbb H$, octonions $\Bbb O$, and sedenions $\Bbb S$.

The *Brahmagupta-Fibonacci 2-Square identity* implies that the norm of the product of two complex numbers $a,b$ equals the product of their norms,

$$||ab|| = ||a||\,||b||\tag{1}$$

Analogous identities (*Euler's 4-Square* and *Degen's 8-Square*) do the same for $\Bbb H$ and $\Bbb O$.

*Question*: Does *[Pfister's 16-Square Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfister%27s_sixteen-square_identity)* imply that two sedenions $a,b$ will obey $(1)$ as well?

Comment: There is a lesser-known version of the sedenions (separate from the usual Cayley-Dickson ones) that do have a multiplicative norm related to Pfister's 16-square identity. In turn they lack the right-distributive property (they form a so-called "division semialgebra"). They were introduced by J. Smith in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869385712379) and I believe they are also mentioned in Conway-Smith's book "On quaternions and octonions".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Note that sedenions have zero divisors, so the norm cannot be multiplicative. (Or it takes $0$ on non-zero sedenions, but that's just wrong).

Example: $(e_3 + e_{10})(e_6-e_{15}) = e_3 (e_6-e_{15}) + e_{10} (e_6-e_{15}) = (e_5 - e_{12}) + (e_{12} - e_5) = 0$. The norms of both $e_3 + e_{10}$ and $e_6-e_{15}$ are $2$.

Comment: Ah, I should have known. I am familiar with the result that two non-zero sedenions $a,b$ can have the product $ab=0$.  However, if we put the constraint that $ab\ne0$, can it be now the case that $||ab||=||a||\,||b||$?

Comment: Check this [link](https://jwbales.us/sedenion.html) for two sedenions $x, y$ such that $|x|\cdot|y|=\sqrt{2}|xy|$.